# Renaming git submodules without moving them

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule set up thus:

.gitmodules

```
[submodule "path/to/submodule"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = user@bitbucket.org:account/repo.git
```

Instead of having to reference it from the project root as 'path/to/submodule', I'd like to just be able to reference it as 'my_submodule'. e.g.

```
git submodule update --remote my_submodule
```

Everything I've read so far about this explains how to *move* the submodule, and that's not what I want to do. I have tried simply changing .gitmodules to

```
[submodule "my_submodule"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = user@bitbucket.org:account/repo.git
```

and
.git > config to

```
[submodule "my_submodule"]
    url = user@bitbucket.org:account/repo.git
    active = true
```

but it just throws
`error: pathspec 'my_submodule' did not match any file(s) known to git`

I hope someone out there can help. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+rename

Comment: @phd thanks. I've already followed the exact process in your reply on that question (as detailed above), but there's nothing in your reply that helps me troubleshoot the error I got

Comment: Well, partially you're right. In addition to config changing you need to move `.git/modules/path/to/submodule` to `.git/modules/my_submodule` and edit the file `path/to/submodule/.git` pointing it to the new `.git/modules/my_submodule`. And partially wrong — you could never use `git submodule update my_submodule` because `git submodule update` takes **the path** to the submodule, not its logical name; see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule . The only way to use `git submodule update my_submodule` is to **move** the submodule, not change its logical name.

Comment: AFAIU the sole purpose for submodules to have logical names is to distinguish them in `.gitmodules` and `.git/config`. And nothing else. People who give beautiful names or rename (change logical names) submodules do this for aesthetic, not practical purposes.

Comment: @phd thank you for the replies. to clarify, I didn't want to give my submodule a "beautiful" name for aesthetic purposes, I just wanted to interact with it without typing out the path every time I need to. I appreciate you reopening my question so that I get some helpful answers and discuss it with people who aren't making assumptions about my intentions or skill level, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [phd has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510548/renaming-git-submodules-without-moving-them#comment129815684_73510548) [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510548/renaming-git-submodules-without-moving-them#comment129815856_73510548), a submodule's "logical name" is—at least currently<sup>1</sup>—used only to locate values within in `.gitmodules` and the files in `.git/modules/`.  You should leave the logical names alone here because they're private to Git itself.  Or, to say this in fewer words: **Don't do that!**

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a *lot* of work going on, over a long time period, in the background, as part of a project to make submodules not be the *sob*-modules that they still are.  Things in the future may change.  That's one reason not to mess with undocumented stuff *about* submodules now.

---

#### Extra information not relevant to the answer but that you should know

It's worth noting a historical oddity: submodules once *were* implemented by storing the `.git` directory / folder (whichever term you prefer) within the working tree *of the submodule*.  That is, if you have:

```
repo/.git     # a top level repository
repo/foo/     # a folder within the superproject containing various files
repo/foo/sub  # a submodule of the superproject, in `foo/sub`
```

then `repo/foo/sub/.git` held the *actual Git repository* for the `foo/sub` submodule of this repository.  Within `repo/foo/sub/.git` you would find the `HEAD` file, the `refs/` directory, the `objects/` directory, and so on.

**This still works,** but it has a rather obvious and nasty drawback.  Suppose we're on the tip commit of branch `develop`, where we've added this new submodule.  We now rewind to `main`, which *does not yet have the submodule*.  Git needs to remove the `foo/thing1`, `foo/thing2`, etc., files, and because there's no submodule, Git wants to remove `foo/sub` as well.

If Git *succeeds* at removing `foo/sub`, the entire submodule repository—not just its checkout—is gone!

To fix this, Git long ago learned to "absorb" submodule Git directories into the superproject, storing them in `.git/modules/` in the superproject.  The `.git` in `repo/foo/sub/` is now a *file* containing the path to the stored repository.  If you have an old arrangement—which you can get by deliberately creating nested repositories before running `git submodule add`—you can run `git submodule absorbgitdirs` to *move* the submodule `.git` (repository proper) into the superproject's `.git/modules` directory.  This makes it safe to check out a historical commit in which there is no such submodule: Git can safely remove the `.git` *file* without destroying the submodule *repository*, and later restore that `.git` *file* when moving to a commit that does use the submodule.

Comment: terrific answer, thank you so much for taking the time! Thankfully, all of the repos I work with on a daily basis employ the `.git/modules`  arrangement and due to the directory structure of their filesystems they're all pretty snappy to work with. But there's always one, right? A pesky, submodule buried so far down that I get tendinitis every time I need to deal with it. At least now I have an appreciation of the logic and that takes the sting out a bit. Thank you!